# Cancelling gain from a filter

Tags: filter, active-filter

I have a bandpass filter with tunable central frequency but the problem with this filter is that as I tune the central frequency its gain for different central frequencies is different. Is there a way to design a inverse filter for nullifying the effect of non uniform filter. I plan to pass the output of the bandpass filter trough this inverse filer.

Thanks :)

Comment: What is the transfer function or circuit diagram of the filter?

Comment: http://www.electronics.dit.ie/staff/ptobin/3chapt07.pdf. This is the circuit diagram of the filter I use

Comment: Where is the tuning element?

Comment: Active filter?, passive filter?  Much more info is needed.  I'm guessing you'll do better fixing your BP filter rather than adding some band-aides to the output.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4yAyUZOQ_Y_RmVqREMwcjF0QW8/view?usp=sharing. I followed the circuit in this diagram. It is the same circuit represented differently. I change Rf to change the central frequency.

Comment: @George A filter with constant gain, tunable central frequency is really hard to design i think.

Comment: Use a state variable filter its Q and centre frequency are independent.

Comment: @Aditya Well if it's a two pole filter made with opamps, (DC-100 kHz or so) then look at the State-Variable filter.  I've used this plenty.  The gain does change with Q... in fact the gain at peak is equal to Q.

Comment: But for my application the bandwidth should be constant but for variable state filter bandwidth changes with center frequency.

Comment: @Aditya, Ahh, a constant bandwidth filter... you should include that in the question.  Do you have a link or schematic.  what frequencies?  So the gain increases with the frequency?

Comment: @George, sorry it skipped my mind. I have to make a bandpass filter with constant BW of 50 Hz. Center frequency should be tunable from 100Hz to 5KHz. I just observed that it doesn't have constant gain for all center frequencies, I didnt look at the behavior for two different center frequencies and realized that it is not the same

Comment: So gain changes from ~ 2 to 100?  You could through away signal with a low pass... but you'd have to stay well away from the corner which would mean rather large attenuation.  (And why do you need the constant band width?)

Comment: Well i need a bandpass filter of constant frequency because I have to make an device that finds that magnitude of frequency components at various frequencies. I proposed to my professor that i will use a bandpass filter with fixed center frequency and use a local oscillator, but my prof denied and he wanted me to implement with an filter with tunable center frequency. And the gain decreases with increase in central frequency.

Answer (score 2):

The article linked in the question states (page 67): -

> The Q-factor and the resonant frequency are not independent in this
>   circuit. For high frequencies, the bandwidth will be the same as that
>   for low frequencies. This, in general, is not a desirable feature. For
>   example, in an audio mixing desk, the equalising section would use a
>   state-variable circuit where the bandwidth changes with the higher
>   frequencies.

It's all there in black and white - research the [state variable filter](http://www.daycounter.com/Filters/StateVariableFilters/State-Variable-Filter-Design-Equations.phtml) and use that instead.

Comment: My application needs constant BW. I chose this circuit for this reason.